# Upgrading React Native from 0.62.2 to 0.63.0 hangs on blank white screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am trying to upgrade react native from 0.62.2 to 0.63.0 manually. I followed [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.63.0).

App builds with no errors but it shows up white screen on start up for both android and ios.

[image]

Dependencies

```
"react": "16.13.1",  
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",  
"react-native": "0.63.0"
```

I tried clearing cache, removing node_modules and pods and then run npm install and pod install. Nothing helped and I still have the same issue.

Comment: I upgraded my project to 0.63 using this command `npx react-native upgrade 0.63.0` without having any problem. Try to upgrade to latest version 0.63.4 may be it's a bug with 0.63.0 version

Comment: I have the same issue with 0.63.4 as well. App builds with no errors but white screen shows up.

Comment: @divyadevineni Any solution ? I am facing same issue on react native upgrade from 0.61.5 to 0.63.4

Comment: We use native base for our app. Native base should also be updated along with react and react native. After upgrading native base white screen issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

hey I just update node packages is not not enough you should update other files too, please check following like
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.63.0